# Creating a web page which contains variable text output

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

As you will probably tell from my question I am a bit of newbie at this.  Anyway, I have been racking my brain on this for days and I cannot find a solution anywhere.

What I am trying to do is create a php page with html text but I want the page to contain a section that displays different text based on a click from menu list.

I know it is possible because I have seen it elsewhere but I cannot seem to figure it our.  I would be grateful for any assistance I can get.

Cheers

Comment: what have you tried? Where have you searched? Have you properly used the search function located at the upper right of your screen? -- this question isn't worth a -1..

Comment: We can only help you if you show us an attempt at coding.  I can provide you with a very generic solution, but I'm sure you can also find one on google

Comment: try using something like http://jsfiddle.net/ to show what you've done so far. This will help get people responding to your question. See jsfiddle's examples to get see how that tool works http://jsfiddle.net/r7MgY/

Comment: Thanks for the responses, as far as code I am not sure what to put that is why I am asking the question.

Comment: Sorry about last short comment.  I have searched this site and google for a way to do it.  I have looked at embedding text and objects and if else codes for html, php and jscript. Unfortunately the answer eludes me hence the reason for my question.

Comment: here is something I have tried, this is just an example though:

Answer (score 1):

perhaps a javascript/jquery approach would be of use to you.

You can assign onclick selector to your links and have them display the different content for you. Such as,

```
var yourMessage = "I like stuff";

$('#linkId').click(function(){
    $('#containerId').html(yourMessage);
}
```

a jsFiddle example with multiple buttons - http://jsfiddle.net/B6QDy/1/
This is of course a starting point for you, how you customise it within your php file is totally your choice.
Hope this helps...